# Neo4j LOADCSV - Splitting column in multiple nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a CSV file that has the following header and rows:

```
Person,Vehicle
John,2006 Toyota Corola
Rick,2014 Honda Civic
Mary,2015 BMW 5Series
```

I want to be able to create the following nodes

```
Person: {John, Rick, Mary}
CarMaker: {Toyota, Honda, BMW}
CarModel: {"Year:2006,Name:Corola", "Year:2014, Name:Civic", "Year:2015, Name:5 Series"}
```

And the following relationships:

```
CarMaker-[:MAKES]->CarModel
Person-[:DRIVES]->CarModel
```

I am using the following statement:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///FakeNulls.csv" AS line
MERGE (person:Person {name: line.Person})
WITH (SPLIT(line.Vehicle," ") AS words |
UNWIND words AS word |
MERGE (carMaker:CarMaker {carMakerName:word[1]})
MERGE (carModel:CarModel {carModelName:word[2], carModelYear:word[0]})
MERGE (carMaker)-[:MAKES]->(carModel)
MERGE (person)-[:DRIVES]->(carModel))
```

However when I run it, I get an error:

```
Invalid input 'S': expected 'n/N' (line 34, column 32 (offset: 1948))
"WITH (SPLIT(line.Vehicle," ") AS words |"
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

-MD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some odd and syntactically invalid parenthesis and | characters in your query, as well as an UNWIND that doesn't make any sense, since you're already using indexes into a collection to get the values you want.

Try this fixed version of the query:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///FakeNulls.csv" AS line
MERGE (person:Person {name: line.Person})
WITH person, SPLIT(line.Vehicle," ") AS word
MERGE (carMaker:CarMaker {carMakerName:word[1]})
MERGE (carModel:CarModel {carModelName:word[2], carModelYear:word[0]})
MERGE (carMaker)-[:MAKES]->(carModel)
MERGE (person)-[:DRIVES]->(carModel)
```